# Allow for first and second choice multiple selection on Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to have a multiple choice list with input to select a first choice and a second choice?

I require this for a seminar registration form where the first choice might be full and we would assign the second choice.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Rating Scale option instead and edit the Custom option as needed to explain the choices:

> [image: rating scale option]

And it should look like this below where they are asked first, second or third choices, between different values:

[image: denim as options on rating scale]

There may need to be some extra custom validation added via the "Show Custom Error" edit to make sure they aren't all made to be first choices.